# How to modify system pop-up message in Joomla?

Tags: joomla3.0

I need to change the system pop-up message in Joomla. The website has 2 languages, so I need to change these messages for both of them.

I checked this path: /public_html/language

However, I cannot find the message.

Answer (score 0):

Check this file 
/language/en-GB/en-GB.ini